# Read a key from registry and populate field in msi installer

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, batch-file, wix, windows-installer

How would one populate a field in a msi installer using an existing key in a registry?

In other words, installer should be able to prefill a licence key field if the product is an upgrade.

I am tasked with maintaining a legacy vb.net program whose installer is based on a Visual Studio 2008 Deployment Project with a custom .bat file run on RunPostBuildEvent success.

The custom .bat files calls a number of cscript WiRunSql.vbs UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE commands. For example two commands that seem crucial are:

```
cscript WiRunSql.vbs %2 "INSERT INTO `Component` (`Component`.`Component`, `Component`.`ComponentId`, `Component`.`Directory_`, `Component`.`Attributes`, `Component`.`Condition`, `Component`.`KeyPath`) VALUES ('RegLicnum', '{DEADBEEF-DEAD-BEEF-DEAD-DEADBEEFDEAD}', 'TARGETDIR', 4, '', 'RegLicnum')"    
cscript WiRunSql.vbs %2 "INSERT INTO `Registry` (`Registry`.`Registry`, `Registry`.`Root`, `Registry`.`Key`, `Registry`.`Name`, `Registry`.`Value`, `Registry`.`Component_`) VALUES ('RegLicnum',2,'SOFTWARE\MyComp\Myproduct\v1.5.x','LicenseNumber6','[LICNUM]','RegLicnum')"
```

I understand the lastcommand creates a db entry for a specific registry in msi thus creating a requirement for the licence key to be saved in the installation process. This in fact actually happens as I verified by using regedit.

My thinking is that one should be able to do something like: `cscript WiRunSql.vbs %2 "SELECT * FROM Registry Where .....`

Thanks to http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msi/authoring.htm i found InstEd and was able to look at the structure of my msi.

Components keys are all C_HASH style entries except one which is RegLicnum (presumably created by the batch script)

There are numerous Tables starting from _Columns and ending with Upgrade

Features are Default Features again with all C_HASH style entries except last one being RegLicnum

Dialogs start with AdminConfirmInstallForm and end with WelcomeForm.

However, where can find **reference** to all of these table entries?
I would expect that MSDN has it somewhere.

Note: My question is somewhat similar to [MSI upgrade and retain registry keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10832482/msi-upgrade-and-retain-registry-keys) but my application has a custom SerialCheckAct table entry, thus I think prefilling the licence field would be the easiest solution.

---

EDIT: My half-understanding is that I need to fill SerialEdit field defined in Control table.
After it is updated by the batch file

```
cscript WiRunSql.vbs %2 "UPDATE `Control` SET `Control`.`Property`='LICNUM',`Control`.`Type`='Edit',`Control`.`Text`='{\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}{53}' WHERE `Control`.`Control`='SerialEdit'"
```

the CustomerInfoForm SerialEdit entry in Control table contains the following:

```
CustomerInfoForm    SerialEdit  Edit    18  216 348 16  3   LICNUM  {\VSI_MS_Sans_Serif13.0_0_0}{53}    CancelButton    |
```

So, I would have to make a reference to this field, in making a RegLocator table entry.
So what should be the format(I plan to add it by hand first using InstEd)?

**Signature_** So this should be a unique and it should not match anything in Signature Table so not to search for file. So anything else goes?

**Root** should be 0x002 to match msidbRegistryRootLocalMachine 0x002   2   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE where entry is rooted

**Key** This I am not sure The full key is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\MyComp\MyProd\v1.1.x, but obviously Wow6432 is system specific, so what should the key be?

**Name** should be LicenceNumber6 (as it appears in regedit),

**Type** should be 0x002 to match msidbLocatorTypeRawValue  0x002   2   Key path is a registry value.

So assuming I add a correct RegLocator entry, how will it "know" to match up to SerialEdit field?

---

EDIT2:
As the accepted answer indicates besides Reglocator table entry it is crucial to create an appropriate AppSearch table entry. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367579(v=vs.85).aspx

---

EDIT3: This is the actual solution(except the actual company/product), I added the following lines to .bat file which is run on Post Build Event:

```
cscript WiRunSql.vbs %2 "INSERT INTO `RegLocator` (`RegLocator`.`Signature_`, `RegLocator`.`Root`, `RegLocator`.`Key`, `RegLocator`.`Name`, `RegLocator`.`Type`) VALUES ('AppSearchSign',2,'SOFTWARE\MyComp\MySoft\MyVer','LicenseNumber6',2)
cscript WiRunSql.vbs %2 "INSERT INTO `AppSearch` (`AppSearch`.`Property`, `AppSearch`.`Signature_`) VALUES ('LICNUM','AppSearchSign')
```

For future reference: AppSearchSign is generic and could be anything else, as long as it is same in both lines, LicenseNumber6 and LICNUM are specific to my application

Comment: Well the tables are here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368259(v=vs.85).aspx is that basically the question?

Comment: Phil, just wanted to thank you for writing The Definitive Guide to Windows Installer! An upcoming 10 year anniversary version perhaps?

Comment: No plans for an update, although I've often thought about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to read a value from the registry during an upgrade why don't you use a Registry search using [RegLocator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371171(v=vs.85).aspx) table?

You can set the name of the search to the exact property name associated with the edit control from the dialog where the license key is entered, so when the user gets to that dialog the field will be pre-populated with the value read from the registry.

Also, you can write a custom action in C++ or C# to read the registry and set the property attached to the MSI field, it's the same thing.

**EDIT**: To link the search with the control all you have to do is to set the name of the search identical with the property of your control. In your case I believe the property is called **LICNUM**.

I built an MSI to which you can look, that contains a registry value search. Download it from the following URL and analyze the tables **RegLocator** and **AppSearch**, this is where you need to make your changes. Nothing should be changed in **Control** table.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5392761/SharedOnPublicForums/demo.msi

Regarding **Wow6432Node**, that do you don't have include in the registry path. The OS does this automatically when running on 64 bit machines. (MSI packages are quite smart ;))

Comment: Thank you! This sounds like what I need, just need to read up more on Installer Database.

Comment: Anytime, don't forget to mark the question as answered if this is your final solution.

Comment: I updated the question with additional information thanks to your suggestion. I am half in dark on how to match what I read from registry to SerialEdit field in CostumerInfoForm.

Comment: See my edit too, it should help you complete your task.

Comment: Thank you for going the extra mile! Very nice to see an actual example. :)

Comment: Btw, Bogdan makes Advanced Installer a product which is definitely worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks Sint, we aim for the best. You probably also noticed the sample MSI is built with Advanced Installer (it took only 2 minutes).